# Swift calculator. "0" remains on the screen

Tags: ios, swift

In the code is one minor problem which I'm trying to solve but have not yet found the solution.
This code is for the calculator.
It is doing right calculations.
But when I press "clear" button, in front of new calculation remains "0".
For example: I press "clear" and after "2". On the screen will appear "02".
I would be very grateful if someone would look at the code and see the solution.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var outputLbl: UILabel!
var btnSound: AVAudioPlayer!

@IBAction func clearBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    playSound()
    runningNumber = ""
    leftValStr = ""
    outputLbl.text = ""
    currentOperation = Operation.Empty
}

enum Operation: String {
    case Divide = "/"
    case Multiply = "*"
    case Subtract = "-"
    case Add = "+"
    case Empty = "Empty"
}

var currentOperation = Operation.Empty
var runningNumber = ""
var leftValStr = ""
var rightValStr = ""
var result = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "btn", ofType: "wav")
    let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    do {
        try btnSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        btnSound.prepareToPlay()
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
    outputLbl.text = ""
}


@IBAction func numberPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    playSound()
    runningNumber += "\(sender.tag)"
    outputLbl.text = runningNumber

}

@IBAction func onDividePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    processOperation(operation: .Divide)
}

@IBAction func onMultiplyPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    processOperation(operation: .Multiply)
}

@IBAction func onSubtractPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    processOperation(operation: .Subtract)
}

@IBAction func onAddPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    processOperation(operation: .Add)
}

@IBAction func onEqualPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    processOperation(operation: currentOperation)
}


func playSound() {
    if btnSound.isPlaying {
        btnSound.stop()
    }
    btnSound.play()
}

func processOperation(operation: Operation) {
    playSound()
    if currentOperation != Operation.Empty {
        if runningNumber != "" {
            rightValStr = runningNumber
            runningNumber = ""

            if currentOperation == Operation.Multiply {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! * Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Divide {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! / Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Subtract {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! - Double(rightValStr)!)"
            } else if currentOperation == Operation.Add {
                result = "\(Double(leftValStr)! + Double(rightValStr)!)"
            }

            leftValStr = result
            outputLbl.text = result
        }

        currentOperation = operation
    } else {
        leftValStr = runningNumber
        runningNumber = ""
        currentOperation = operation
    }
}
}
```

Comment: add a conditional to your numberPressed to check `if whatever == "0"` replace it otherwise append it to the string

Comment: Where does the `0` come from after pressing `clear`? You are dealing with text rather than numbers when adding digits so leading zeros remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0` came from `Operation.Empty`
I solved this problem in the following way:
`if (runningNumber == "0") {
    runningNumber.remove(at: runningNumber.startIndex)
}`
I'm not sure that this solution is optimal but now the calculator works perfect
I thank everyone who took the time to help. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you IBOutlets (maybe you have clear button that is also
   binded to numberPressed method)
2. Check tags of your buttons
3. Add log inside numberPressed() to check if something goes wrong with
   runningNumber